# Validar número carnet de identidad de Cuba con expresiones regulares

Tags: regex

Estoy haciendo una tarea para el colegio y debo hacer un CRUD con AJAX, Bootstrap, y PHP.

Para agregar un usuario se necesitan ciertos campos y uno d ellos es el número de identidad. Contiene 11 digitos. El formato es por ej `99062709883` donde los dos primeros números son el año d nacimiento, los próximos dos el mes y los próximos dos el día. Los restantes 5 números no siguen un patron específico.

Hasta ahora he validado los restantes campos con expresiones reguares y tengo un codigo bastante limpio. Hasta ahora la expresión q tengo es esta `/^\d{11}$/` pero no es la adecuada ya q solo me comprueba q tiene 11 dígitos y no es lo q necesito. Quería saber si pueden ayudarme a hacer una expresión regular para validar este campo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu pregunta fue cerrada porque es demasiado amplia... tu expresion regular solo va a validar el formato, pero no va a validar si cumple reglas particulares. Lo que estas describiendo es mucho mas facil de validar con controles simples. De igual forma, evita volver a hacer una pregunta que fue cerrada por no ser clara. Ademas, supongo que vos queres validar en php no?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Creo que [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562111/looking-for-a-regex-to-validate-cuban-identity-card) tienes respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: NO creo q usando solamente expresiones regulares puedas resolver este problema, ya que este carnet de Cuba tiene una estructura muy especifica, lo 6 primeros digitos corresponden a la fecha, aqui entran validaciones tales como si la fecha es valida, si es año bisiesto, en fin todas las validaciones que lleva una fecha, el 7mo digito corresponde al siglo, si va del 0 al 4 es siglo 20, del 5 al 8 siglo 21 y si es el 9 es siglo 19, los digitos 8vo y 9no, son digitos consecutivos, el 10 es el sexo, si es par es hombre, impar es mujer, Continuara...

Comment: Y por ultimo el 11no digito es el digito de control que es una formula matematica que se aplica usando los digitos anteriores para validar el carnet, ademas esta la validacion de que debe tener 11 caracteres y todos deben ser numeros

Comment: @Japv q me recomienda usted?

Comment: @Japv y cuál sería la fórmula matemática de la suma de control!? Me interesa.

Comment: @Francisco en cuba todo eso es casi  que secreto, eso lo saben las autoridades y no lo dicen, asi q imaginate

Comment: @Japv gracias, no sabía sobre los dígitos indicadores del siglo, de echo para generar una fecha de nacimiento con un año de 4 dígitos a partir del número de identidad lo hice comparando con el año actual y restando un siglo, pero esto no es fiable para personas muy mayores. Pondré en práctica tus especificaciones.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d{2}([0]?[0-9]|[1]?[0-2])([0-2]?[0-9]|[3]?[0-1])\d{5}$
```

Prueba ésta, debería funcionar algo mejor ya que  que este formato evita incoherencias como mes 13 o día 32 del mes, así que si bien no es exactamente un filtro confiable, evita algunos errores de digitación

Comment: Pulsá en [edit] y explicá cómo funciona esta expresión regular. Puede que vos entiendas cómo funciona, pero otros tendrían que _descifrar_ su funcionamiento. Leé [answer].

Comment: y por que crees que funciona mejor?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Lo que pasa es que este formato evita incoherencias como mes 13 o día 32 del mes, así que si bien no es exactamente un filtro confiable, evita algunos errores de digitación, un abrazo, espero ser de utilidad, si no es el caso me excusas.